# Google Analytics ga setVar?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I cant find the equivelent setVar function for the analytics.js version of the API.  Thought this would be easy to find in the dev guide but apparently not where I am looking...  Does it exists? Trying to build a custom filter for some tracking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setVar was deprecated even with the asynchronous code  - it was replaced by setCustomVar which in turn was now replaced by custom dimensions and custom metrics in analytics.js. So no, it does not exist anymore.

However [custom dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/customdimsmets) should mostly do the trick (only that as far as I can tell there is no way to retrieve the value for a custom var in the browser which was possible for custom vars in the visitors scope in ga.js).